# beans.xml mapping for a Custom Validation Annotation

Tags: java, spring, validation, annotations, jsr

I am writing a custom validation annotation. This involves creating a @interface annotation and an implementation of ConstraintValidator. For instance, the @interface could be defined as follows:

```
@Target( { METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyConstraintValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String message() default "{my.error.message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Is it possible to use this style of definition but without the 'validatedBy' declaration, and instead define the mapping between @interface and ContraintValidator implementation in a spring beans.xml file?